# Simplifying/re-expressing a generating function for an integer sequence using Mathematica

Tags: symbolic, integer-sequence

Consider the sequence of natural numbers generated by:

$f(n) = 2 n + (-1)^n/2 - 1/2$,

for $n > 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ (positive integers):

i.e., {1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 16, 17, 20, ...}

Inspired by [this mathematics question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275532/how-do-i-create-an-equation-for-an-alternating-sequence-of-numbers/2275556#2275556), how would one use `FunctionExpand`, `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `FindSequenceFunction`, various substitution rules, and other *Mathematica* functions to *derive* (not confirm) that

$$f(n) = \left\lfloor {4 \over 3} \left\lfloor {3 n \over 2} \right\rfloor \right\rfloor ,$$

where of course $\lfloor x \rfloor$ or `Floor[x]` (read "floor of $x$") is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$, or that

$$f(n) = 2n - (n\!\!\!\!\!\!\mod2)?$$

Answer (score 2):

If an over-complicated solution suffice...

```
f[n_] := Floor[4/3*Floor[3/2*n]]
Table[{k, Simplify[f[3*2*m + k], m \[Element] Integers] /. 
    m -> (n - Mod[n, 3*2])/6}, {k, 0, 5}];
```

Where the second line we are just changing `m=3*2*m + k`, with k a number between 0 and 5.

```
FullSimplify[InterpolatingPolynomial[%, Mod[n, 3*2]], n \[Element] Integers]
```

Next, we interpolate the result in `k`, which is basically `Mod[n, 3*2]` and simplify.

We arrive at this beauty:

```
2 n - 1/15 (Mod[n, 6] - 4) (Mod[n, 6] - 2) Mod[n, 6] (Mod[n, 6] (2 Mod[n, 6] - 13) + 16)
```

Which can be numerically tested, and it gives the same result as the original f[n].

My approach (lame) works with any function of this kind and the end result is absurdly complex.

BTW, this function remembers me Collatz...

Comment: Thanks @T.F.  This is a reasonable approach, but as you found a bit incomplete.  I was hoping there might be some substitution rules that led to the curious "floor-floor" functionality.  Worth an up-vote, but (as you noted), surely not an acceptance as a solution.  Moreover, you (basically) *confirmed* the answer, since you started with the floor-floor function—not *derived* the answer (as my question requests).  My function is monotonic; Collatz is non-monotonic.

Comment: Dummy me... I copied the wrong function definition... It was supposed to be:


    f[n_] := 2 n + (-1)^n/2 - 1/2
    Table[{k, 
       Simplify[f[6 m + k], m \[Element] Integers] /. 
       m -> 1/6 (n - Mod[n, 6])}, {k, 0, 5}];
    FullSimplify[InterpolatingPolynomial[%, Mod[n, 6]], 
        n \[Element] Integers] /. Mod[n, 6] -> n - 6 Floor[n/6] // Simplify

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer.